# How to display all the days of a month in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I have written a query like

```
SELECT 
    Sum(a.in_total) as Totall, 
    DATEPART(dd, a.in_date_issued) as dateissued
FROM         
    dbo.IN_Invoices as a  
WHERE
    DATEPART(mm, a.in_date_issued) = 5 
AND DATEPART(yyyy, a.in_date_issued)= 2015 
AND a.sy_id='DPI'
AND EXISTS(SELECT DISTINCT cl_id as clid 
           FROM dbo.cloi_clientorderitems as c  
           WHERE c.masterorderid=a.masterorderid)
--AND c.cl_id NOT IN ('100001_DPO')) 
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(dd, a.in_date_issued)
ORDER BY dateissued ASC
```

This query will written the out put like

```
Total| day
100  |  1
0    |  3
150  |  10
-
-
200  |  31
```

Expected output

```
Total| day
100  |  1
150  |  2
0    |  3
600  |  4
-
-
200  |  31
```

Please help me in that query.

Comment: As you used `group by datepart(dd,a.in_date_issued )` surely you would also `order by datepart(dd,a.in_date_issued ) asc`? Try it and let me know.

Comment: no same result..not getting expected result as i shown

Comment: Ah, well. It was a shot in the dark. I've done so little with sql-server that it falls outside of my area of experiences.

Comment: Give it time, sometimes the right expert is working hard at their day job and may find your question during some down time.

Comment: you must get the result in a single statement?

Comment: ya already i am getting result but the days i want serially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
DECLARE @y INT;
DECLARE @m INT;

SET @y = 2015;
SET @m = 5;

WITH 
m AS(SELECT 1 AS d UNION ALL SELECT d+1 FROM m WHERE d < datediff(d, DATEADD(mm, @m - 1, CAST(@y AS VARCHAR(8)) + '0101'), dateadd(m, 1, DATEADD(mm, @m - 1, CAST(@y AS VARCHAR(8)) + '0101'))))

SELECT isnull(Totall, 0) AS Totall, m.d AS dateissued
FROM m
LEFT JOIN(

SELECT  SUM(a.in_total) AS Totall ,
        DATEPART(dd, a.in_date_issued) AS dateissued
FROM    dbo.IN_Invoices AS a
WHERE   DATEPART(mm, a.in_date_issued) = @m
        AND DATEPART(yyyy, a.in_date_issued) = @y
        AND a.sy_id = 'DPI'
        AND EXISTS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                            cl_id AS clid
                     FROM   dbo.cloi_clientorderitems AS c
                     WHERE  c.masterorderid = a.masterorderid )
                   --and c.cl_id not in ('100001_DPO')) 
GROUP BY DATEPART(dd, a.in_date_issued)
)t ON m.d = t.dateissued
ORDER BY m.d ASC
```

Comment: getting this error "Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 4
Must declare the scalar variable "@d".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 13
Must declare the scalar variable "@d".
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.
  "

Comment: What is the version of SQL Server?

Comment: instade of passing date('20150501') can we pass year and month?

Comment: Try replace `DECLARE @d DATE = '20150501';` with `DECLARE @d DATE; SET @d = '20150501';`

Comment: ya i got now ...and instade of passing date('20150501') can we pass year and month?